# highchart minimize code redundancy

Tags: javascript

I am using HighCharts to draw graph and there are some code redundancys that i want to minimize

the code looks like this :

```
data = [{
        y: pageViews[0],
        color: colors[0],
        drilldown: {
            name: date[0],
            categories: ['a','b','c'],
            data: [photosR[0], ratingsR[0], searchesR[0], socialR[0]],
            color: colors[0]
        }
    }, {
        y: pageViews[1],
        color: colors[1],
        drilldown: {
            name: date[1],
            categories: ['a','b','c'],
            data: [photosR[1], ratingsR[1], searchesR[1], socialR[1]],
            color: colors[1]
        }
    }]
```

this is a drill down bar chart in highchart. I want to create a loop instead of writing the below code 2 times

```
y: pageViews[0],
color: colors[0],
drilldown: {...}
```

I feel that it has to do with object, but haven't learn a lot about it yet

Comment: I'm afraid that it is not related with highcharts, but with javascript.

Comment: Have you tried a loop? Show us your attempts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume, that all your arrays have the same length, so it is safe to loop any of them.
This should work for you:

```
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < pageViews.length; i++) {
   data.push({
      y: pageViews[i],
      color: colors[i],
      drilldown: {
         name: date[i],
         categories: ['a','b','c'],
         data: [photosR[i], ratingsR[i], searchesR[i], socialR[i]],
         color: colors[i]
      }
   });
}
```